# Switch background image based on device size swift

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit

I'm trying to switch my background image based on the device height pixel, I picked up some answers through stackoverflow and reddit however the error I am getting is really grinding my gears. Below is my code

```
func addBackground() {
        
        // screen width and height:
        var Imgname = "6sSignUp"
        let width = UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.width
        let height = UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height
        
        let imageViewBackground = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
        imageViewBackground.image = UIImage(named: Imgname)
      
        
        switch height {
            case 568:
                //iPhone SE, iPhone5, iPhone 5s
                Imgname = "5sSignUp"
                break;
            case 1334:
                //iPhone 6, 6s, 7
                Imgname = "6sSignUp"
                break;
            case 1920,2208:
                //iPhone 6 plus, 6s plus, 7 plus
                Imgname = "6PSignUp"
                break;
            default:
                Imgname = "SignUpHome"
                break;
        }
       
        imageViewBackground.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageViewBackground.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageViewBackground.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        imageViewBackground.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        imageViewBackground.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        imageViewBackground.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        view.addSubview(imageViewBackground)
        view.sendSubviewToBack(imageViewBackground)
    }
```

I am getting an error "**reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x600001014400 "UIImageView:0x7f8f2af0af30.top"> and <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x600001014440 "UIView:0x7f8f2af09cc0.top">**"

I understand it has something to do with my top anchor but I can't seem to access superview when trying it programmatically. Could anyone shed some light on what i'm doing wrong perhaps?

Comment: add imageViewBackground as subview before you can anchor it

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik wow, I feel so stoopid :(. Thank you for providing that answer